# Choosing a connector for a 12-wire keyboard scan matrix

Tags: connector

This is my first real electronics project, so please do let me know if I’m doing something stupid here. :)

I’m wiring up an old set of organ pedals to a Teensy LC for use as a MIDI controller, so I’m planning for each of the 32 pedals to have an individual magnetic reed switch, and then to connect all 32 switches to a keyboard scan matrix (12 wires, either 6×6 or 8×4). Ideally I’d like to use something like [this](http://www.musanim.com/mam/organproject.html) construction, where the switches are on a separate board beneath the pedals (*edit*: and the Teensy will probably be in an enclosure on top of the unit). In order not to have lots of loose wires running all over the place, I’m thinking that I should use a cable to connect the board with switches to the Teensy.

But...what kind of cable? The page I linked to mentioned a Centronics connector, but that seems like overkill if I only need 12 pins. For the moment, I’m leaning toward a DE-15 connector, since it’s the same as used for VGA, so I won’t have to make my own cable. Or maybe a DA-15, for which I could use IDCs and ribbon cable... but ribbon cable is unshielded, right? So would it be appropriate to use it outside of an enclosure?

Or am I going about this engineering process all wrong?

I *think* I’m looking for something that satisfies the following criteria:

- At least 12 pins.
- Connectors readily available.
- Connectors rated for a reasonable number of mating cycles.
- Cables readily available (e.g. VGA) or easy to make cheaply (e.g. ribbon/IDC).
- Cables suitable for use outside an enclosure.

Any of these are up for debate. :)

Comment: Why not put the Teensy into the pedalboard and have a MIDI interface with DIN connector for output? The only downside is the need for a pedalboard PSU.

Comment: Using IDC cables and connectors  saved a lot of soldering headaches. Just beware that if you want to use more then  one pedal at a time you need a matrix with a diode per switch as per [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420115/checking-how-many-inputs-reed-switches-are-active-using-minimal-gpio-pins/420123#420123]

Comment: @Transistor The plan is indeed to mount the Teensy on the pedalboard and wire up a DIN connector for MIDI output, so I don’t know what you’re suggesting I do differently. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Oldfart: Yes, I was planning to use a diode matrix...thanks! Were you able to get reasonable performance from ribbon cables outside an enclosure? I don’t want to cause excessive interference or have to replace my cable every month. :)

Comment: I assumed that the connector was because the Teensy is to be separate from the pedals. If not then just wire them up permanently perhaps.

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, I probably wasn’t too clear about that from what I wrote; I’ve expanded it now. I assume I’d want the Teensy in an enclosure for protection, though, so that still doesn’t solve the problem of getting 12 input wires to it easily, does it?

Comment: Ribbon cables are fine even when long, but you should not use very high scan frequencies. e.g. 1KHz should work. If you have spare strands ground them and put them between the driving and receiving groups.

Comment: Agreed with @Oldfart that you're fine with ribbon cables so long as your scan frequency is fairly low (which is fine, scanning fast would just waste power).

Comment: @Oldfart That’s very helpful. Since MIDI only runs at 9600 baud if I understand correctly, I doubt that there would be any point to scanning at more than 2 KHz tops, if I did the math right.

Comment: MIDI runs at 31.25 K baud ....... you could reduce the number of IO pins if you use a demux/mux combination 
 ..... `74ls138` and `74HC151`

Comment: @jsotola There wouldn’t be any point to doing that *and* using a scan matrix, would there? (And you’re right about the baud rate. Not sure how I got the wrong number in my head. That’s still probably only a 4 KHz scan maximum, though.)

Comment: @Oldfart Hmm. With that scan frequency, would a VGA cable be a better choice?

Comment: @jsotola So are you suggesting running the scan matrix into the shift registers, or using the shift registers instead of the scan matrix? Your choice of words is still unclear to me.

Comment: The scan frequency has nothing to do with the baudrate, it has to do with how fast you can press keys. I doubt your feet would get to even 10 Hz.

Comment: @Oldfart Right, but the scan frequency is partly constrained by the baud rate, because there’s no point scanning for key events faster than I can transmit them over MIDI. Also, while my feet might not get to 10 Hz, a 0.1-second delay between playing a note and corresponding MIDI output would be completely unacceptable.

Comment: @jsotola Right, they’re not shift registers; I think I was confusing 151 with 595. Oops. :P I’ll take a look at that approach, but since I *have* enough pins on the microcontroller, is there really any advantage in doing it that way?

Comment: +1 for trying to use the D-sub shell size designations correctly.  Have a look at the Wikipedia page to get a clear idea and then it is easy to remember.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature

Comment: If you plan to have the pedals and the box joined then you do not have to use a traditional bulkhead connector.  You can simply use pin headers and pins that are IDC crimped onto ribbon cable.  If you make a hole in the boxes where they meet then you just pass the cable through the slot and connect it to your two parts with the flat cable.

Comment: @KalleMP I don’t really want to make too many irreversible structural modifications to the pedals, so if you’re suggesting drilling a hole in the pedal housing to pass the cable through, I’m not terribly enthusiastic about that idea. Fortunately, I don’t think that will be necessary.

Comment: I’m not sure why this was closed. It is not a  question seeking “recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them”, but rather of what types of generic connectors I should be looking at for a particular use case. And I did “describe [my] situation and the specific problem”. Isn’t this exactly the sort of question that belongs on electronics.SE?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough diagram of a circuit that uses a mux and a demux to scan a key matrix.
It uses 6 data lines

Couple of  suitable ICs are 74ls138 and 74HC151.

The controller in the diagram could be replaced by a 5 bit counter.

The actual controller would then require only 3 data lines, `reset`, `clock` and `data`

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqieA0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7BJNS.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful to study even if I don’t wind up doing it this way.

Comment: A single-chip solution would be to use an [I2C I/O expander chip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf), which would allow you to scan up to 64 keys with just four lines in the cable: power, ground, clock and data.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think I looked at that at one point, and figured (perhaps naïvely) that it would perform less well than directly wiring the scan matrix. Also, I²C seemed like a comparatively large amount of work to program for (though I’m sure some library code is available). I could be wrong on either or both of those assumptions, though; I know just enough to be dangerous here. :)