# Addressing 45 Inputs Down to 6 pin Output

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, microprocessor, addressing, chip-design

I'm looking for a chip which could minimize ~45 button inputs down to an 6 pin input for use with Raspberry Pi.

I know this is a simple problem and it has likely been solved before, but as an absolute beginner, most of the responses were either too theoretical or too high-level for me to utilize effectively.

The cheaper the chip/easier the process, the better.

Thanks you for any help!

Comment: You are looking for a keyboard encoder. Take it from here.

Comment: What do you mean by "remaining bits"? Do you have 11 input bits for the buttons or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 45 Buttons, reduced to 6 bits for addressing purposes. The remaining 5 (out of 11) are used for program instructions. So yes I need 11-bit input to the Raspberry Pi in total.

Comment: How these 5 are relevant to the question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're absolutely correct, I revised the question to avoid this confusion.

Comment: One could use 6 shift registers connected in serial, with 3 IO pins to read the 48 bits in. Scan them periodically; or use diodes to create an interrupt to tell the Pi when to read them.  There are also chips that will create an interrupt when an input is changed.

Comment: have a look at this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421921/choosing-a-connector-for-a-12-wire-keyboard-scan-matrix/421954#421954

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the gpio by scanning the buttons as shown in this example schematic.
Modify to suit your needs.

[image]

UPDATE: As @DHLaurelT pointed out, this would require 14GPIO to get the job done.  So it would have to be an intermediary circuit that scanned the buttons and then sent the results to the Pi.

Comment: This schematic is helpful, and I may be misreading, but wouldn't this require 7+7 = 14 GPIO pins for 45 buttons theoretically? (My apologies if I'm deeply mistaken)

Comment: @DHLaurelT Doh! You are right.  So it can not be done directly into the Pi, but would require an intermediary circuit.  At that point though, then it could use a uart to tell the Pi what button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

[Charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing#Input_data_multiplexing) works just as well with switches as it does with LEDs. 8 bidirectional I/O lines can access up to 7 × 8 = 56 switches.